# How to convert 85 Volts DC to 5 Volts DC

Tags: voltage, dc, dc-dc-converter

I have a LED driver which model is
**HC(8-18)X1W**
Output: 300mA

and it gives 85 Volts output.
I want 2 outputs from it, as parallel
1- Same
2- 5 volts

### Amazon specs

Output : Constant current 300mA 72~96Vdc for 300mA LEDs

Input : 24-48V External Power supply

Comment: I doubt this LED driver has a constant voltage output. It rather has a 300mA constant **current** output, which makes it pretty hard to put a voltage regulator behind it.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You may need to show some effort and progress to make this question answerable.

Comment: DC to DC to DC conversion  24Vdc to 72~96 300mA (CC) to 5V ?? mA is inefficient. Bad choice.

Comment: Thanks for help.   It have constant current of 300mA and volts are not constant, upto 85

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much current you’ll use from the 5V supply. If it’s a small amount you can simply use a linear regulator that withstands 85V as input, for instance check the ZXTR2005P5-13. But make sure the power dissipation over it is not too much. You can calculate it by multiplying (85V - 5V) * Ic, where Ic is the desired current from the 5V supply.

Comment: I need a very minimal current on output, with 5 volts. Just need to operate a 5 volts relay

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question of how to convert 85V to 5V.  A module like this one could do it.

VIN = 40V to 160V, VOUT = 5.0V, 3W

RDE03110S05

The cost is $33.15 at Digikey

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/xp-power/RDE03110S05/1470-4569-ND/8535646

But LED drivers are usually constant current outputs, so you may not really have an 85V input to begin with.